# Node formidable returns empty fields and files

Tags: node.js, formidable

I could as well move to another module but I'm curious about what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to integrate formidable in an already existing app by intercepting the request before it hits `body-parser`, and viewing the files and fields that hit the server but it returns plain objects for both objects.

Client side, I'm submitting the form using `FormData` and inspecting the form using the `entries()` method and `for of` just to be sure it is loaded, and yes, it is. Yet, the server does not pick it.

The server code looks like this:

```
 app = app.use(multipart)
 .use(require("body-parser").urlencoded({limit: "45kb", extended: true}))
 .use(cookieSession({secret: "mmay", maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000, httpOnly:  true,
 expires: new Date (Date.now() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000))
 }))
 .use(static(__dirname + "/public"))
 .use("/admin", admin);

 function multipart(req, res, next) {
if (req.method == "POST" && req.headers["content-type"].indexOf("multipart/form-data") == 0) {
    console.log("running");
    var newFoodsForm = new formidable.IncomingForm(), util =    require("util");
    newFoodsForm.uploadDir = path.join(__dirname + "images");
    newFoodsForm.keepExtensions = true;

    newFoodsForm.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files})); // returns {fields: {}, files: {}}
    })
   } else next();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @I Want Answers Did you find the answer for this?

Comment: @SivaBathula It's very likely I used an alternative as no solution was forthcoming. It's been 4+ years; I don't recall the outcome